# Past data into React copied from Excel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, react-native, web

I am creating a web interface and have created a table where values can be entered or copied from Excel. While pasting data works correctly, I am struggling to achieve dynamic insertion.

If the number of pasted rows is greater than the rows in the table, I need to automatically create the required number of rows.

I am having difficulty implementing this.

`my content:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import DataSheet from 'react-datasheet';
import 'react-datasheet/lib/react-datasheet.css';
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

const ExcelTable = () => {
  const [grid, setGrid] = useState([
    [{ value: 'Column 1' }, { value: 'Column 2' }, { value: 'Column 3' }, { value: 'Column 4' }, { value: 'Column 5' }, { value: 'Column 6' }],
    [{ value: '' }, { value: '' }, { value: '' }, { value: '' }, { value: '' }, { value: '' }], // Initial empty row
  ]);

  const handlePaste = async (e) => {
    const clipboardData = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
    const pastedText = clipboardData.getData('Text');
    
    try {
      const workbook = XLSX.read(pastedText, { type: 'binary' });
      const sheet = workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]];
      const data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(sheet, { header: 1 });

      setGrid((prevGrid) => {
        const newGrid = [...prevGrid];

        // Add new rows if needed
        const rowsToAdd = Math.max(0, data.length + 1 - newGrid.length);
        for (let i = 0; i < rowsToAdd; i++) {
          newGrid.push(Array(newGrid[0].length).fill({ value: '' }));
        }

        // Update data in the grid
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          if (!newGrid[i + 1]) {
            newGrid.push(Array(newGrid[0].length).fill({ value: '' }));
          }

          for (let j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
            if (newGrid[i + 1] && newGrid[i + 1][j]) {
              newGrid[i + 1][j].value = data[i][j];
            }
          }
        }

        return newGrid;
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error parsing pasted data:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <DataSheet
        data={grid}
        valueRenderer={(cell) => cell.value}
        onCellsChanged={(changes) => {
          const newGrid = [...grid];
          changes.forEach(({ row, col, value }) => {
            newGrid[row][col] = { ...newGrid[row][col], value };
          });
          setGrid(newGrid);
        }}
        onSelect={() => {}}
        onPaste={handlePaste}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ExcelTable;
```